# How Can I Make This Python Code More Usable And Readable?

Tags: python, oop, usability, readability

Beginner in python, but been programming for about 5 years now. I suspect I have a lot to learn about doing things the object oriented way, but I know the basics. I planned on programming a calculator that shows it's work for the challenge and knowledge i'll gain from it. I just started and this is what i've got, and it just looks really ugly to me. How would you have done it differently?

P.S. This is just a simple script to take the problem from inside parenthesis, add it up, show the work, then evaluate the full problem.

```
import re

def EvalParenths(problem):
    contents = ""
    if re.match( "\(", problem):
        contents = re.match("(\(.*\))", problem)
        parenthsAnswer = contents.group(0)
        problem = problem.replace(parenthsAnswer, '')
        print "   \ \n   "  + str(eval(parenthsAnswer)) + problem
        problem = problem.replace(parenthsAnswer, '')
        answer = eval(parenthsAnswer+problem)
        print "    \ \n    " + str(answer)
    else:
        print "Didn't Find Parenthesis"

def ProblemHasParenths(problem):
    return re.match( "\(", problem)

"""""
Example Problem: (12/4)*2

"""""

problem = raw_input()

if ProblemHasParenths:
    EvalParenths(problem)
```

Comment: It is quite readable to me, and I don't know a bit about Python.

Comment: Thanks :)

I sometimes feel like i'm doing everything wrong since i've always coded by myself, and just don't feel as if I know enough about OOP and such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make a simple calculator you could try implementing [Shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).

But if you want to go with regex approach I'd still do it a little differently:

```
import re

#In python functions/methods usually are lowercase
#and words are seperated by _ while classes use CamelCasing
def eval_step_by_step(expression):
    """Evaluates math expression. Doesn't do any error checking.
        expression (string) - math expression"""

    print expression
    #For pretty formating.
    expr_len = len(expression)
    #While there's parentheses in the expression.
    while True:
        #re.match checks for a match only at the beginning of the string,
        #while re.search checks for a match anywhere in the string.

        #Matches all numbers, +, -, *, / and whitespace within parentheses
        #lazily (innermost first).
        contents = re.search("\(([0-9|\*|/|\+|\-|\s]*?)\)", expression) 
        #If we didn't find anything, print result and break out of loop.
        if not contents:
            #string.format() is the Python 3 way of formating strings
            #(Also works in Python 2.6).

            #Print eval(expression) aligned right in a "field" with width
            #of expr_len characters.
            print "{0:{1}}".format(eval(expression), expr_len)
            break

        #group(0) [match] is everything matching our search,
        #group(1) [parentheses_text] is just epression withing parentheses.
        match, parentheses_text = contents.group(0), contents.group(1)
        expression = expression.replace(match, str(eval(parentheses_text)))
        #Aligns text to the right. Have to use ">" here
        #because expression is not a number.
        print "{0:>{1}}".format(expression, expr_len)

#For example try: (4+3+(32-1)*3)*3
problem = raw_input("Input math problem: ")

eval_step_by_step(problem)
```

It doesn't exactly work the same as your function, but you could easily implement modifications into your function to match mine. As you can see, I've also added a lot of comments to explain some stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the algo recommendation. No rush on the rewrite, i'm about to go to bed anyway :)

I'm reading up on the shunting-yard algo right now!

Comment: BTW, the reason i'm wanting to make a calculator that shows steps is I believe it will help me get into artificial intelligence type programming

Comment: I've updated with some code, sorry for delay something came up.

Comment: Oh yeah, you could also write it using recursion (probably more pythonic).

Answer (score 5):

Some problems:

```
contents = re.match("(\(.*\))", problem)
```

When it's given the input `(1+2)/(3+4)`, it's going to try to evaluate `1+2)/(3+4`.

It also doesn't go all the way into nested parentheses, for this you would need to use recursion.

I think you should make another attempt at this before you "look at the answers".

Comment: Will do when I get up in the morning!

Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably replace occurrences of

```
re.match( "\(", problem)
```

with

```
problem.startswith("(")
```

In

```
contents = re.match("(\(.*\))", problem)
parenthsAnswer = contents.group(0)
```

you don't check to see whether contents matches or not so if you pass it the input "(1" you'll get an exception when you try to evaluate contents.group(0)

Don't every use `eval` in a real program!

You could use [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) to make a full parser, but I think it is the kind of thing everyone should try on their own as an exercise at least once!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you match only for the double and matching parentheses? The first match for a single `(` is not really necessary because if the match for the doubles fail, this means there are no expression for you to evaluate.

```
import re

def eval_parentheses(problem):
    contents = re.match("(\(.*\))", problem)
    if contents:
    ...
    else:
        print "Couldn't find parentheses!"
```

Also, the parentheses selection algorithm could be improved a bit for nested parens etc.